# add columns with random values to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe df with two existing columns `name` and `birthdate` for which I want to overwrite the values with random values.

For column `name` I want to have a string with a random set of letters with a fixed length (say 10). The string should be randomized for each row so all rows don't get the same string.

for column `birthdate` I want a string on format `YYYY-MM-DD`. I want each row to have a random value between `1960-01-01` and `2019-01-01`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create random Strings with

```
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(size))
```

and random Dates with

```
month = random.randint(1, 12)
str(random.randint(1960, 2018)) + '-' + str(month)+'-' + (str(random.randint(1, 28)) if month == 2 else str(random.randint(1, 30)) if month % 2 == 0 else str(random.randint(1, 31)))
```

don't forget to `import random` and `import string`.

To create an array with the shape of the dataframe create an numpy.ndarray with the same size

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.ndarray(2, len(dataframe[0]))
```

and than give it the right values through an loop

```
for y in range(len(dataframe[0])):
    arr[0, y] = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(size))
    month = random.randint(1, 12)
    arr[1, y] =str(random.randint(1960, 2018)) + '-' + str(month)+'-' + (str(random.randint(1, 28)) if month == 2 else str(random.randint(1, 30)) if month % 2 == 0 else str(random.randint(1, 31)))
```